# Combinatorial Proof: How many length-n lists can we form using the elements in {1,2,3} [PROOF]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to prove that

$2\times(3^0) + 2\times(3^1) + 2\times(3^2) + \cdots+ 2\times(3^(n-1)) = 3^n - 1$
by answering the question "how many length-n lists can we form using the elements in $\{1,2,3\}$ in which the elements are not all 3 on both sides?" for both the LHS and RHS

So far, I assume that the RHS is $3^n - 1$ because it represents the number of lists of length $3$ minus the set of all $3'$s.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: in a list where elements are not all 3, there must be an earliest element which is not 3. When counting into strings, break up into cases by where this element occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: at every place in the list you can put one of $1,2,3$.